# How to find similarities in matrix?

Tags: python, math, numpy, matrix, scikit-learn

I have a huge matrix (10*10k). I'd like to know if there is a way to find similarities between lines.

Let's give an example of matrix: 4*5

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
0     0     1     0
2     3     4     5
2     3     2     3
0     0.1   1     0
0     0     1     0
```

I'd like to know if there is a statistical theory to determine the similaritieis between data.

Line 1 is 100% like Line 5 Line 2 is 50% like Line 3

But how can I deal with numbers that are near to each others.

Line 4 and Line 5 have -nearly- same values. same how can we find a way to calculate probability of similarities ? Is there any function on python, numpy, scikit-learn that calculate that ?

```
import numpy

mat= numpy.random.random((30, 30))

def find_similarities(line,targeted_line):
    ..
```

Comment: This isn't really a numpy question as such. I would say you're better off doing a bit of thinking about why you're trying to do this. Then figure out what exactly you want to do to your matrix. Until then I think it's premature to go searching for numpy functions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `similarity measures` or `similarity functions`. Calculating the [Euclidean Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) or the [Cosine Similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) between each row will solve your problem. You can also benefit from Hamming distance or the Jaccard index by adapting the idea to your needs. You can compute most of such similarities in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.